# Shallow-copying into a protocol buffer's bytes field

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

Suppose I have a proto with a bytes field:

```
message MyProto {
    optional bytes data = 1;
}
```

An API that I do not control gives me a pointer to source data and its size. I want to make a `MyProto` out of this data *without deep copying.* I thought this would be easy to do, but it appears to be impossible. Deep copying is easy with `set_data`. Protobuf provides a `set_allocated_data` function, but it takes a pointer to a `std::string`, which does not help me, since (unless I'm mistaken) there is no way to make a `std::string` without deep copying into it.

```
void populateProto(void* data, size_t size, MyProto* message) {
    // Deep copy is fine, I guess.
    message->set_data(data, size);

    // Shallow copy would be better...
    // message->set_allocated_data( ??? );
}
```

Is there any way to properly populate this proto (such that it can be serialized later) without deep copying the source data into the bytes field?

I'm aware that I could manually do the serializing right away, but I'd rather not, if possible.

Comment: In this API that you don't control, does it allocate/own the buffer for the source data, or do you have to allocate it yourself and have the API fill it in?

Comment: @Mark no, the API owns the buffer and I can't tell it where to allocate the data.

Comment: Ugh, that's too bad, otherwise you probably could've worked around it by asking the protobuf message for a mutable string and then feeding your API its underlying buffer.... Are you stuck with protobuf? I seem to remember MessagePack being a lot more flexible about this kind of thing.

Comment: Yep, this is part of a large project that uses protobuf.

Comment: Just curious - are you free to change the .proto definition?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Great question. The options are:

1. **UPDATE: `StringPiece` is obsolete according to [an online developer discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/protobuf/0Bjiat1zMLU), which may render this option moot**. If you can alter your .proto file, consider implementing the `ctype` field option for [`StringPiece`](https://github.com/google/protobuf/blob/master/src/google/protobuf/stubs/stringpiece.h), Google's equivalent of C++17 [`string_view`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view). This is how Google would handle such a case internally. The `FieldOptions` message already has [semantics for StringPiece](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.descriptor.pb#FieldOptions_CType.details), but Google has not yet open-sourced the implementation.

   ```
   message MyProto {
       bytes data = 1 [ctype = STRING_PIECE];
   }
   ```
2. Use a different protocol buffer implementation, perhaps only for this particular message type. [protobuf-c](https://github.com/protobuf-c/protobuf-c/wiki/Generated-Code#message-methods) and [protobluff](https://github.com/squidfunk/protobluff/blob/master/include/protobluff/core/string.h) are C-language implementations that look promising.
3. Feed a buffer to your 3rd party API. I see from the comments that you can't, but I'm including it for completeness.

   ```
   ::std::string * buf = myProto->mutable_data();
   buf->resize(size);
   api(buf->data(), size); /* data is contiguous per c++11 std */
   ```
4. **NON STANDARD:** Break encapsulation by overwriting the data in a string instance. C++ has some gnarly features that give you enough rope to hang yourself. This option is not safe and depends on your `std::string` implementation and other factors.

   ```
   // NEVER USE THIS IN PRODUCTION
   void string_jam(::std::string * target, void * buffer, size_t len) {
     /* On my system, std::string layout
      *   0: size_t capacity
      *   8: size_t size
      *  16: char * data (iff strlen > 22 chars) */
     assert(target->size() > 22);
     size_t * size_ptr = (size_t*)target;
     size_ptr[0] = len; // Overwrite capacity
     size_ptr[1] = len; // Overwrite length

     char ** buf_ptr = (char**)(size_ptr + 2); 
     free(*buf_ptr); // Free the existing buffer
     *buf_ptr = (char*)buffer; // Jam in our new buffer
   }
   ```

*Note: Don't do this in production.* This is useful for testing to measure the performance impact if you did go the zero-copy route.

If you go with option #1, it would be great if you could release the source code, as many others would benefit from this capability. Best of luck.

Comment: For Solution 3, the buf->reserve(size) should be buf->resize(size).

Comment: @WeidongLian Good catch. Updated. Thanks!